# changing bash environments in linux?

Tags: bash

Currently I am in /xhbin/tcsh. which command changes me to /bin/bash? Do I need to change the $SHELL variable or something like that?

Comment: Changes you where for how long?

Comment: permanently I what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change shells temporarily, simply run the new shell. They're like any other program.

```
snow:~> bash

grawity@snow:~$
```

Use `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to go back.

---

To change the shell permanently, use `chsh`:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

You must provide the full path to the new shell (use `which bash` to find out). Also, `chsh` may not work on centralized logon systems.

Answer (score 2):

Just run /bin/bash? That will only last for your current session though.

Answer (score 0):

As @grawity mentions, chsh may not always work.  I have a server for which my login shell is ksh and I like to use bash interactively. This is my ksh `.profile`:

```
# my login shell is /bin/ksh
# this profile should spawn bash without re-invoking this profile

bash_opt='--noprofile'
[ -r .bash_profile ] && bash_opt='--login'

echo "spawning bash $bash_opt"
exec /usr/bin/bash $bash_opt
```